# GitLab SSH Issue - it doesn't accept my SSH no matter the format

Tags: ssh, gitlab, key

I need some help with GitLab as I am trying to add SSH keys. No matter the format I use it always shows the same message. In the past I have managed to add them by removing comment lines or the initial and last entries.

Current samples:

fails
[image]

fails
[image]

fails
[image]

No matter how I clean it it keeps failing. Does anyone know how to pass this?

Comment: the key above is a sample, needles to say I will create a new one and of course that it it had never been used before, it was fresh for that example

Comment: How did you generate the key? What command did you use? Did you copy the key from a file? What was the filename?

Comment: @Kenster I did like this https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen, using RSA and saving both public and private keys. I used the content inside the public key to paste above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ssh-keygen.exe which is part of Git for Windows:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM
```

That will override `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`, and you can copy the public key, which should be valid and recognized by GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

I must also say that following these instruction here did the trick for me before reading the answer above https://dev.to/sndrx/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-key-and-use-it-in-gitlab--42p1

I also tested the answer above and I found the same way. Thank you